# Stanley says $E_{n+1,k+1}=E_{n+1,k}+E_{n,n-k}$ about counting alternating permutations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations, recurrence-relations

I'm having some trouble understanding the solution that R. Stanley gives to the following:

> Let $n\geq k \geq 0$ and let $E_{n,k}$ be the number of alternating permutations of $[n+1]$ that starts with $k+1$. Show that:
> $$
> E_{n+1,k+1} = E_{n+1,k} + E_{n,n-k}.
> $$

Stanley gives the following hint:
Show that $E_{n+1,k}$ is the number of alternating permutations of $[n+2]$ with first term $k+1$ and second term unequal to $k$,
and that $E_{n,n-k}$ is the number of alternating permutations of $[n+2]$ with first term $k+1$ and second term $k$.

Can someone help me understand it?

Comment: "$[n+1]$" means what?

Comment: @PaulSinclair the set $\{1, 2, \dots , n+1\}$.

Comment: Next question: per the wikipedia article, some authors define "alternating permutations" with the demand that the second element in the permutation be smaller than the first, while others do not make that restriction. Which choice does R. Stanley make?

Comment: @PaulSinclair the same one, the second element is smaller than the first.